# How do I get React Router basename to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

I am trying to get my react app to work on the file system in IE Edge browser. So far I have gotten this far.

```
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'
let appHistory = useBasename(createHistory)({
    basename: '/build'
});
<Router history={appHistory}>
<Route path={window.location.pathname} component={App}>
```

And this way I can actually see a page render, but the routes do not work
I also get this path in the Edge browser file:///C:/C:/ ... etc. Why does it have two C:/'s?

In chrome I get this error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A
>   history state object with URL 'file:///C:/build/windows' cannot be
>   created in a document with origin 'null' and URL
>   'file:///C:/src/myproject/build/index.html'.

Comment: Maybe you got this code from a guide and I'm very wrong, but I feel like setting the path to `window.location.pathname` shouldn't work. You should specify a string as your path, ex : `path={'/'}`

Comment: actually it only works with window.location.pathname from the file system. The only problem now is that pushstate does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `useRouterHistory` instead of `useBaseName`:

```
import { Router, Route, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

const history = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({
    basename: '/dist'
});

<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```